# Dynamically make a vertical radio group with jQuery mobile and Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dynamic, radio-group

I've been trying to tackle this for hours. Ive even looked at other similar examples here on stack Overflow but they just aren't helping.

```
success :  function(data) {       
    var subscriptionJSONObject = data; //{"cost":7.0,"duration":30,"id":7},{"cost":120.0,"duration":365,"id":8}
    $('<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="paypalFieldset"></fieldset>').appendTo('#paypalContent');                     
    $('<legend id="paypalLegend">Select a subscription:</legend>').appendTo('#paypalFieldset');                     
    $.each(subscriptionJSONObject,function(i) {
          $('<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-'+i+'" id="'+subscriptionJSONObject[i].id+'" value="'+subscriptionJSONObject[i].cost+'"/>').appendTo("#paypalFieldset"); 
          if(subscriptionJSONObject.cost != -1){
          $('<label for="radio-choice-'+i+'">'+subscriptionJSONObject[i].duration+' day subscription for only R'+subscriptionJSONObject[i].cost+'.00</label>').appendTo("#paypalFieldset");     
          } else {
               $('<label for="radio-choice-'+i+'">Free subscription</label>').appendTo("#paypalFieldset");     
          }
    });
    $("#paypalContent").trigger("create");
}
```

This is part of my success function from my ajax call. The buttons are displaying, the legend also displays but they do not form the style of a vertical radio group with jquery mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken the `.trigger("create")` call should be made on the page itself (rather than the individual widgets). This seems to be implied here in the jQM documentation:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

By this logic, your final statement might read:

```
$("#paypalContent").closest("div[data-role=page]").trigger("create");
```

If this doesn't help, I've also had luck with using `.destroy()` followed by `.trigger("create")` but I doubt that this is considered good form.

Good luck!